# match xml element with given namespace qualified attribute using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to extract an element from an XDocument using the following:

```
    private bool ContainsEntity(FileInfo filePath, string entityType, int id, string field, string value)
    {
        try{
        var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath.FullName);
        var entities = doc.Descendants(entityType);
        var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1");
        var attr = new XAttribute(ns + "uuid", id);
        var specificEntities = entities.Where(y =>
            {
                var atts = y.Attributes();
                return atts.Contains(attr);
            });
        return specificEntities.Any(ent =>
            ent.Elements(field).Any(f => f.Value.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

        }catch{return false;}
    }
```

the element in question in the xml document looks like:

```
 <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<feed xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"" xmlns:sdata=""http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1"" xmlns:http=""http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/http/2008/1"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:mybi=""http://schemas.sage.com/mybi/import/2011"" xmlns:cs=""urn:cs"">
<author>
<name>Sage UK</name>
</author>
<category />
<generator version=""Sage Business Sync 1.0.0.0, Resources Package 0.1.0"" />
<id />
<title>Sage 200 UK Synchronization feed</title>
<mybi:contractVersion>1.2.5</mybi:contractVersion>
<mybi:resourceKind>depotStore</mybi:resourceKind>
<entry xmlns="""">
  <author>
  <name>Sage UK</name>
</author>
<id>1</id>
<title>operatingCompanyResource</title>
<updated>2014-12-19T10:32:43.501+00:00</updated>
<sdata:payload>
  <depotStore sdata:uuid=""1"">
    <operatingCompanyReference>1</operatingCompanyReference>
    <originalType>
        operatingCompanyWarehouse
      </originalType>
    <type>
        operatingCompanyWarehouse
      </type>
    <name>warehouse1</name>
  </depotStore>
</sdata:payload>
</entry>
</feed>";
```

the problem is that the attribute is not matched, so specificEntities is always a zero length collection.  The problem appears to be with the namespace prefixing of the attribute name, but I cannot see how to initialize attr  to the desired value.

Comment: Can you post the a block of XML inclusing the definition of `sdata`? Not just the element.

Comment: @RahulSingh I have editted the question with and example of a full xml document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
var specificEntities = entities
    .Where(y => y.Attributes(nsSys + "uuid").Any(a=>a.Value.Equals(id.ToString())));
```

or:

```
var specificEntities = entities
    .Where(y => y.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name==(nsSys + "uuid") && a.Value.Equals(id.ToString())));
```

Why:

- You can't create an attribute like this `var attr = new XAttribute(ns + "uuid", id);` and expect it to be equal to some attribute in your xml document. The new attribute doesn't belong to the document and thus the alias for the namespace is random (certainly not "sdata")
- You can't use `Attributes().Contains(attr)` for that reason too (also because it compares the references of objects and not the objects themselves)
- `id` is an `int` so you should convert it to string before comparing it to the value of some attribute (which is string). Otherwise `Equals()` method will, again, compare objects, and "1" =! 1
- also, using `entities.Where(y => y.Attribute(name).Value.Equals(id.ToString()))` is dangerous here. What if you're looking for elements named `"depotStore"`, and there's no attribute named `"sdata:uuid"` there? (It will throw a nullexception). You should check for null or use `Attributes().Any()`

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed this by changing the method to

```
private bool ContainsEntity(FileInfo filePath, string entityType, int id, string field, string value)
{
    try{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath.FullName);
    var entities = doc.Descendants(entityType);
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1";
    XName name = ns + "uuid";
    var specificEntities = entities.Where(y => y.Attribute(name).Value.Equals(id));
    return specificEntities.Any(ent =>
        ent.Elements(field).Any(f => f.Value.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

    }catch{return false;}
}
```

it seems that creating an explicit XName to use in the where was the trick.